# Compare array with file and form groups from elements of array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a text file with letters (tab delimited), and a numpy array (`obj`) with a few letters (single row). The text file has rows with different numbers of columns. Some rows in the text file may have multiple copies of same letters (I will like to consider only a single copy of a letter in each row). Letters in the same row of the text file are assumed to be similar to each other. Also, each letter of the numpy array `obj` is present in one or more rows of the text file.

Below is an example of the text file (you can download the file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hrs6AFa5jQWiTQH_aoTr0hR_Igl-2J1e/view?usp=sharing) ):

```
b   q   a   i   m   l   r
j   n   o   r   o
e   i   k   u   i   s
```

In the above example, the letter `o` is mentioned two times in the second row, and the letter `i` is denoted two times in the third row. I will like to consider single copies of letters rows of the text file.

This is an example of `obj`: `obj = np.asarray(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])`

I want to compare `obj` with rows of the text file and **form clusters from elements in `obj`**.

This is how I want to do it. Corresponding to each row of the text file, I want to have a list which denotes a cluster (In the above example we will have three clusters since the text file has three rows). For every given element of `obj`, I want to find rows of the text file where the element is present. Then, I will like to **assign index of that element of `obj` to the cluster which corresponds to the row with maximum length** (the lengths of rows are decided with all rows having single copies of letters).

Below is a python code that I have written for this task

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=r'\t+', header=None, engine='python').values[:,:].astype('<U1000')
obj = np.asarray(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    globals()['data_row' + str(i).zfill(3)] = []
    globals()['clust' + str(i).zfill(3)] = []
    for j in range(len(obj)):
        if obj[j] in set(data[i, :]): globals()['data_row' + str(i).zfill(3)] += [j]

for i in range(len(obj)):
    globals()['obj_lst' + str(i).zfill(3)] = [0]*data.shape[0]  

    for j in range(data.shape[0]):
        if i in globals()['data_row' + str(j).zfill(3)]:
            globals()['obj_lst' + str(i).zfill(3)][j] = len(globals()['data_row' + str(j).zfill(3)])

    indx_max = globals()['obj_lst' + str(i).zfill(3)].index( max(globals()['obj_lst' + str(i).zfill(3)]) )
    globals()['clust' + str(indx_max).zfill(3)] += [i]  

for i in range(data.shape[0]): print globals()['clust' + str(i).zfill(3)]

>> [0]
>> [3]
>> [1, 2, 4]
```

The above code gives me the right answer. But, in my actual work, **the text file has tens of thousands of rows**, and the **numpy array has hundreds of thousands of elements**. And, the above given code is not very fast. So, I want to know if there is a better (**faster**) way to implement the above functionality and aim (using python).

Comment: So... your code actually **works**? If that is true, ask the question in [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), they will find a way to optimise your code perfomance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `merge` after a `stack` on `data` (in pandas), then some `groupby` with `nunique` or `idxmax` to get what you want

```
#keep data in pandas
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=r'\t+', header=None, engine='python')
obj = np.asarray(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])

#merge to keep only the letters from obj
df = (data.stack().reset_index(0,name='l')
          .merge(pd.DataFrame({'l':obj})).set_index('level_0'))

#get the len of unique element of obj in each row of data
# and use transform to keep this lenght along each row of df
df['len'] = df.groupby('level_0').transform('nunique')

#get the result you want in a series
res = (pd.DataFrame({'data_row':df.groupby('l')['len'].idxmax().values})
         .groupby('data_row').apply(lambda x: list(x.index)))
print(res)

data_row
0          [0]
1          [3]
2    [1, 2, 4]
dtype: object
```

`res` contains the clusters with the index being the row in the original `data`